# Netbeans Absolute Include Path

Tags: php, netbeans

In my project, `require`, `include`, etc. reference the absolute path. Autoloading is not being used. I also have it set up as a "Remote Web Site". The web server is Linux, and the machine I run Netbeans on is Windows.

Is there a way to configure Netbeans so that it translates the ***absolute server path*** to the ***local path*** in my project?

Instead of this:

```
require_once '../path/to/file.php';
```

Have this:

```
require_once '/absolute/path/to/file.php';
```

---

If I enter my code using the first example, Netbeans will give me path completion. In the second example, it has no idea where `/absolute/` is, so it doesn't do path completion. In the first example I can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `click` to open the file. I would like to maintain that completion support while using absolute paths.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  You are at the mercy of `Netbeans` on how it will generate the absolute path in a configuration file.  You do understand the two values are exactly the same to `Netbeans` right?

Comment: The problem is your second example, is incomplete, its not the absolute path.  You would need a drive letter for it to work.

Comment: It's a "Remote Web Site", which is running on Linux. It *is* the absolute path. The machine I run Netbeans on is Windows. I am looking for a way to set up a mapping so that Netbeans can automatically translate the path.

Comment: ( if it was the absolute path then would work.  The fact you have a leading `/` in your example is suspicious to me

Comment: The leading slash is how *nix defines an absolute path. It's the root path.

Comment: **Its not the root path on Windows though.**  Windows understands what `../` is because that's a valid relative path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20057/discussion-between-sonny-and-ramhound).

Comment: I didn't say that it was. I said I want Netbeans to do a mapping/translation.

Comment: Try the full Windows network path. Entertain my suggestion

Comment: That would break the code on the server.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to accomplish, and I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Yes; I understand what you want to do.  But your using a Linux style syntax for the absolute path which isn't understood by the Windows Netbeans software.

Comment: ...hence the desire for a mapping. There are debugging mappings, etc. that already do this *type* of thing in other places.